# How to make nginx serve a different version of a script to specific hosts?

Tags: nginx

We have a JS script which customers add to their websites via a `<script>` tag. When visitors access the customers' websites, the script does some work and sends the results back to our server.

Unfortunately many ex-customers, and even many never-ever customers, continue to use this script on their websites.

It's not a huge deal, but it means our servers have to process a lot of visitor data from non-customers.

Is there a way I can tell nginx to serve these particular non-customers an alternate (blank) version of our script?

Thanks.